# CSS Overlay other div outside of its parent

Tags: html, css

```css
.div1{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
.div2{
    background:green;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
.div3{
    background:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;
   
}
.div4{
    background:yellow;
    height:30px;
    width:90%;
    margin-left:25px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:-10px;
    overflow:visible;
}
.div5{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
    Contents of container 1
</div>
<div class="div2">
    Contents of container 2
</div>
<div class="div3">
   <div class="div4">
    Overlay
    </div>
</div>
<div class="div5">
    Content of container 5
</div>
```

Given html and css in the followings, I would like to overlay the `div2` (`green` color) by `div4` (`yellow` color), let' say by half of `div2`'s height. How can I achieve this without using absolute positioning since I have other complicated elements (for header and footer). I was trying to achieve this with `negative top margin` and `overflow visible` but still it does not work as I expect.
Please note that `div2` and `div4` are not from the same parent div.

Here is the HTML

```
 <div class="div1">
        Contents of container 1
    </div>
    <div class="div2">
        Contents of container 2
    </div>
    <div class="div3">
       <div class="div4">
        Overlay
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="div5">
        Content of container 5
    </div>
```

and here is the CSS:

```
.div1{
    background:red;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
.div2{
    background:green;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
.div3{
    background:black;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;

}
.div4{
    background:yellow;
    height:30px;
    width:90%;
    margin-left:25px;
    text-align:left;
    margin-top:-10px;
    overflow:visible;
}
.div5{
    background:blue;
    color:white;
    width:100%;
    height:30px;
}
```

Comment: You can’t use a div inside another div to overlay something without having the outer div also overlaying without using `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`. This is how CSS and HTML work.

Comment: Something like [**this**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xweJzK)?

Comment: Yes exactly! I will try on my code. thanks anywaw